# use UILongPressGestureRecognizer on disabled UIButton

Tags: ios, uikit, uigesturerecognizer

I have a `UIButton` that has an `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` attached to it.

If the button is enabled I receive events from the gestureRecognizer.
However, if the button is disabled (i.e. `button.enabled = NO`) I don't receive those event.

Is there any way to receive events from a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` if the `UIButton` is not enabled?

Answer (score 0):

A few options:

- Don't actually disable the button, just set a flag internally and don't perform the button action when the flag is false.  Side effect is that the button will still look like it's working.
- Create another button over top of the disabled button that has no visible appearance.  Attach a Long Press to that as well.  When you enable the visible button, disable the invisible button and vice versa.
- Put a Long Press on the parent view use the gesture delegate to see if it's on top of your button:

  ```
  - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
  {
      if (touch.view == theButton)
      {
          // Perform your action
      }
  }
  ```